# Check if a string has cumulative uppercase letter

Tags: c#, linq

I want to have a function that return substring of a string that has a 'cumulative' uppercase letter inside it.

The string passed to the function can be anything.

Example:

`check("ProcessFlowPFDiagram")` // return ["PF"]

`check("MinistryOfEducationMOEProgram")` // return ["MOE"]

`check("WhateverStringWEStringIsPassedONE")` // return ["WE", "ONE"]

`check("nouppercaseletterhere")` // return [""]

`check("ALLUPPERCASE")` // return [""]

`check("test123TESTghedEFGjhgcdhj")` // return ["TES", "EF"]

`check("GREATgreatGoodJOB")` // return ["GREA", "JOB"]

any idea on how to implement the function?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by 'cumulative', please explain better. Returning the first two uppercase characters would satisfy all your test cases. Taking the first n/2 (rounded down) upper case characters? Remove the word "Diagram" and take the first n/2 upper case characters? ????

Comment: Your specifications need to be more precise. Your expected result for "ALLUPPERCASE" makes it seem like lowercase characters are required later in the string, but that doesn't explain why "GREATgreatGoodJOB" returns "JOB".

Comment: That said, your "question" needs to be more than just specifications. Stack Overflow is not about posting specifications and than waiting until someone writes your code. Show what you tried for two reasons: it shows where you need help specifically (and then it becomes a question) and usually own efforts clarify what words fail to describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string foo = "WhateverStringWEStringIsPassedONE";
// match Uppercase "[A-Z]" letter at least 2 in a row "{2,}", followed by "(?=   )" uppercase letter "[A-Z]" or "|" <end> "$"
var matches = Regex.Matches(foo, @"[A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z]|$)");

foreach (var match in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(match);
```

[Edit] I saw it doesn't cover the "all uc" case. But I would check this in an extra if, to not make the regex more complex.

Answer (score 1):

You need to better explain the problem. But based on your examples, I gather you're looking for groups of 2+ uppercase letters, not including uppercase letters that are followed by a lowercase letter. You can solve this problem a variety of ways. One way is using regular expressions. This regular expression gets you pretty close ([test online](https://regex101.com/)):

```
([A-Z]+)([A-Z][^A-Z]+|$)
```

The only example input where I get different output is `ALLUPPERCASE`. Are you sure that's the expected output? If so, why?

Again, you need to better define the problem. But this should at least give you a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not completely clear to me. I don't know why `"ALLUPPERCASE"` should return an empty result. Hence I handle it in the very beginning as a special case. See this code:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Check(string input)
    {
        if(input.All(char.IsUpper))
        {
            return new List<string> {""};
        }
        
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(var c in input)
        {
            if(char.IsUpper(c))
            {
                buffer.Append(c);
            }
            else
            {
                if(buffer.Length > 1)
                {
                    buffer.Length--;
                    result.Add(buffer.ToString());
                }
                buffer.Clear();
            }
        }
        
        if(buffer.Length > 0)
        {
            result.Add(buffer.ToString());
        }
        
        if(!result.Any())
        {
            result.Add("");
        }
        
        return result;
    }
```

First, we handle the special case. Then we loop through the string and append upper case letters to the buffer. If there is a non-upper case letter and there is more than one char in the buffer, the input of the buffer is saved in a temporary list and cleared again. This list is the result list, which is returned at the end of the method.

This code passes all your testcase: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AGf1Pf